# OpenBox autostart in OpenSUSE?

Tags: linux, opensuse, openbox

How can I use autostart with OpenBox (in OpenSUSE)? Previously xfce was installed to run in the first place.

I have added

```
xfce4-panel &
```

to `autostart` in `/etc/xdg/openbox/` and `autostart` `~/.config/openbox/` to no avail.

`xfce4-panel &` from terminal works. My autostart looks like this:

```
   #
   # These things are run when an Openbox X Session is started.
   # You may place a similar script in $HOME/.config/openbox/autostart
   # to run user-specific things.
   #

   # If you want to use GNOME config tools...
   #
   #if test -x /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon >/dev/null; then
   #  /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon &
   #elif which gnome-settings-daemon >/dev/null; then
   #  gnome-settings-daemon &
   #fi 

   # If you want to use XFCE config tools...
   #
   #xfce-mcs-manager &
   xfce4-panel &
```

Comment: Can you show us your autostart.sh?

Comment: Recent Openbox versions prefer `autostart` over `autostart.sh`, if present. Check you don't have those. Also check that the command gives no error when run from a terminal.

Comment: @enzotib: I've tried both autostart and autostart.sh to no avail. I didn't choose openbox either, it was an accident but I would like to keep it. I don't have an .xinitrc in ~/ either?

Comment: How do you start openbox?

Comment: @enzotib: I don't know. I've added lxde to the displaymanager to no avail. xfce4-panel loads from terminal but not from autostart? I'm not sure what happens. It's a fresh installation. I've even deleted .cache/session folder, too. Previously xfce was installed to run in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found a solution but a quick workaround is to start openbox-session when power on. I created the file .xinitrc in my home folder and add exec openbox-session to that file. This makes the kernel loads openbox-session when power on and then openbox loads and execute the autostart file in ~/.config/openbox. However it's still a mystery to me how openbox is loaded when power on. I've looked in /etc/sysconfig/displaymanager and ~/.cache/session but I couldn't find it. I hope it's not loaded twice with my .xinitrc workaround. This workaround is working for me.